# Error: multiply-defined labels

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

Below given example gives this error.
! SIAM Label Error: There were multiply-defined labels.
Correct multiply-defined labels.

```
\documentclass[final,leqno,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamltex1213}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\title{USING SIAM'S \LaTeX\ MACROS\thanks{This work was
supported by the Society for Industrial and Applied
Mathematics}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{example}

\begin{figure}[H]
\subfloat[Read Availability (13 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{readavail13.jpg}}
\label{Worst Quorum Size}
\hfil
\subfloat[Read Availability (40 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{readavail40.jpg}}
\label{Optimal Quorum Size}
\caption{Read Availability}
\label{ra}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\subfloat[Write Availability (13 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{writeavailthrt.jpg}}
\label{Worst Quorum Size}
\hfil
\subfloat[Write Availability (40 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{writeavailforty.jpg}}
\label{Optimal Quorum Size}
\caption{Write Availability}
\label{figsim}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

All labels defined are unique and not repeated.The **siamlatex1213.cls** file can be found at http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php.

Comment: Multiply-defined labels are no errors in itself, but rather confusing.

Answer (score 3):

It should be rather a comment, but the code is too long.

```
\documentclass[final,leqno,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamltex1213}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\title{USING SIAM'S \LaTeX\ MACROS\thanks{This work was
supported by the Society for Industrial and Applied
Mathematics}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{example}

\begin{figure}[H]
\subfloat[Read Availability (13 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{readavail13.jpg}}
\label{Worst Quorum Size}
% The first occurence of this label
\hfil
\subfloat[Read Availability (40 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{readavail40.jpg}}
\label{Optimal Quorum Size}
% The first occurence of this label
\caption{Read Availability}
\label{ra}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\subfloat[Write Availability (13 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{writeavailthrt.jpg}}
\label{Worst Quorum Size}
% The second occurence of this label
\hfil
\subfloat[Write Availability (40 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{writeavailforty.jpg}}
\label{Optimal Quorum Size}
% The second occurence of this label
\caption{Write Availability}
\label{figsim}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```